# Qual o equivalente da arrow function?

Tags: javascript

Este codigo esta em um botão. São duas duvidas,

Como escrever essa linha sem usar arrow function?

E sempre que eu executo a primeira vez ele me volta undefined mas na segunda funciona, acho que tem que adicionar promises? Como resolve isso?

```
        let results;
        this.$refs.myMap.$mapObject.data.toGeoJson((geojson) => {
          results = JSON.stringify(geojson, null, 2);
        });
        console.log( results );
```

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso não faz diferênça ter arrow function ou uma funcão anonima, por isso podes simplesmente mudar `.toGeoJson((geojson) => {` para `.toGeoJson(function(geojson){`. Mas se fazes isso por questão de compatibilidade repara que o `let` também deve ser mudado para `var`.

Em relação ao problema assíncrono podes usar promises, ou usar como está (com callbacks). De qualquer maneira o que tens de fazer é colocar o código que precisa desse `results` **dentro** da função. Ou seja, criar um fluxo de código a partir dessa callback.

Usando JavaScript "antigo" (sem `let` e sem `arrow function`):

```
this.$refs.myMap.$mapObject.data.toGeoJson(function(geojson){
    var results = JSON.stringify(geojson, null, 2);

    // aqui podes chamar uma outra função que precise de `results`
    console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let results;
this.$refs.myMap.$mapObject.data.toGeoJson(function(geojson){
     results = JSON.stringify(geojson, null, 2);
});
console.log( results );
```

Sem usar arrow functions